$A\cup B$ is countable when $A$ and $B$ are countable
Statement: if $A$ and $B$ are countable then their union is countable.
Proof: There must exist two bijections $f$ and $g$ respectively for set $A$ and $B$ by the definition of countable set. We have to take account of two situations whether $A$ and $B$ are disjoints:

If $A$ and $B$ are disjoints, consider function $h : A \cup B \to \mathbb N$, if $x$ is in $A$ then we set $h(x)=2f(x)$ and if $x$ is in $B$ then we set $h(x)=2g(x)+1$ .
This clearly shows there is an bijection , by definition $A\cup B$ must be countable.
We define $A\cup B = A \cup (B\setminus A)$ where intersection of $A$ and $B \setminus A$ is empty. We can incorporate the method demonstrated above, by convention it is acceptable for us to omit the construction.

This proves that two sets whose union must be countable if they are both countable. Q.E.D.

Not very clear... but yes, we can consider only the "disjoint" case because $A \cup B = A \cup (B \setminus A)$

Countable does not imply a bijection with $\Bbb{N}.$ You should argue about the case where both $A,$ and $B$ are in bijection with $\Bbb{N},$ where $A$ is countably infinite, and $B$ is finite, and where both are finite.

You are re-defining union in terms of union? I think you have to mop up the language

@Chickenmancer We used to use the term at-most countable to include finite sets as countable sets. I don't consider finite sets to be countable so I wouldn't consider that case either. See, for example, Rudin's "Principals of Mathematical Analysis". Countable sets are those that are in one-to-one correspondence with the natural numbers.

@JohnDouma This wasn’t a comment on your response. I think your language is accurate. This comment was for the OP. They did not use at most in their write up.

Let $A$ and $B$ be countable sets. Then, there are injections $f: A\to\Bbb Z^+$ and $g: B\to\Bbb Z^-$. Let $\tilde g: B\setminus A\cap B\to\Bbb Z^-$ be the restriction of $g.$ Obviuosly $\tilde g$ is an injection. Define,
$$h: A\cup B\to\Bbb Z$$
by
$$h(x)=
\begin{cases} 
f(x),& x\in A\\
\tilde g(x),&x\in B\setminus A\cap B
\end{cases}$$
which is obviously an injection. Therefore, $A\cup B$ is countable.

"We can incorporate the method demonstrate above"
So you are trying to use the case where your two sets are countable and disjoint with A and B \ A. However B \ A isn't necessarily countable, as for example you could have B = A. Thus your first case cannot always be applied.
Edit in response to OP's comments: in case 1 you supposed "there exists two bijections f and g respectively for set A and B by the definition of countable set". I therefore assumed you meant "countable" as "countably infinite". If you meant "at most countable", then what happens when A or B is finite?

It is common to use the word countable for "finite or in bijection with $\mathbb N$"

It is possible, then "in bijection with $\mathbb{N}$" would be refered to as "countably infinite". According to OP, countable should mean "in bijection with $\mathbb{N}$", and thus "finite or in bijection with $\mathbb{N}$" would be refered to as "at most countable".

If $A$ and $B$ are both finite, or if one is finite and the other is countably infinite, there is nothing to prove. Hence assume both $A$ and $B$ are countably infinite; thus there exists a bijection of each of these sets with the natural numbers. List the elements of $A$ as an infinite column (say, the column entries are $a_1, a_2, \ldots, ...$) and the elements of $B$ as an infinite row (say, the row entries are $b_1, b_2, \ldots, ...$).
$A \cup B$ is a subset of the column and row entries taken together; so it is enough to show that the set comprising all the column and row entries is countable. A bijection of this set with the natural numbers can be given by the listing as follows:
$\{ a_1, a_2, b_1, a_3, b_2, a_4, b_3, \ldots, a_{n+1}, b_n, \ldots, ... \}$, which exhausts all the row and column entries; hence this set (with possibly repeated elements) is countable, and hence so is the subset $A \cup B$ (with distinct elements).
Edit: More generally, Cantor's diagonalization method (which he used to prove that the set of rational numbers is countable) can be modified to show that a countable union of countable sets is countable.

If both sets are finite, the proof is straightforward. If one set is countably infinite and the other set is finite, one can simply pull a Hilbert's Hotel for finitely many guests maneuver.
If both sets are countably infinite, then we must have functions $f:\mathbb{N}\to A$ and $g:\mathbb{N}\to B$ where $f$ and $g$ are both bijections. Consider the function $h$ defined as follows
$$h(n) = \begin{cases}
    f(\frac{n+1}{2}) & \text{if }n\text{ is odd} \\
    g(\frac{n}{2}) & \text{if }n\text{ is even.}
\end{cases}$$
Note that every element of $A$ is hit and so is every element of $B$ (given $a\in A$, we have $h(f^{-1}(a)\cdot2-1)=a$, and given $b\in B$, $h(g^{-1}(b)\cdot2)=b$). Therefore, $h$ is surjective.
Also, the transformations of odd integers by $\frac{n+1}{2}$ and even integers by $\frac{n}{2}$ are both injective, and the functions $f$ and $g$ are injective. Moreover, $f$ and $g$ have disjoint codomains, since we can assume WLOG that $A$ and $B$ are disjoint (using the tactic from the question that $A\cup B=A\cup(B\setminus A)$), so no two inputs are mapped to the same output. Thus, $h$ is injective as well.
We have now shown that there exists a bijection between $\mathbb{N}$ and $A\cup B$. Therefore, $\mathbb{N}\sim A\cup B$, i.e., $A\cup B$ is countable (in this case, countably infinite).

Just because f and g are injective doesn't mean an output of f can't equal an output of g.... (credit to rafilou for the idea)

@TobyM I've updated my answer to explicitly mention the idea of using the set difference trick mentioned in the question.

If both are finite then their union is finite.
Same goes for one finite and the other countably infinite.
Say $A$ is finite and $B$ $א_0$.
Then:
A possible bijection is:
$\phi:A\rightarrow \{1,...n\} , \;\phi:B\rightarrow \{n+1,...\}$.
Hence let us ask what happens when both are countably infinite:
Define:
$\Xi_A(x)=1,  x \in A$
$\Xi_A(x)=0\;, x\notin A$
And:
$\Xi_B(x)=1, x \in B$
$\Xi_B(x)=0, x \notin B$
Thus:
$\Xi_{A\cup B}=\Xi_A(x)+\Xi_B(x)-\Xi_{A\cap B}(x)$
This can be easily proved (try!).
